# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 - Unable to connect to maven.google.com

Tags: android, maven, android-studio-3.0

I follow Migrate to the New Plugin doc,add google maven "https://maven.google.com"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
//        jcenter {
//            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
//        }
        //这里是 LeanCloud 的包仓库
        maven {
            url "http://mvn.leancloud.cn/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
        }
        //MPAndroidChart仓库
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        //google
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.8.11'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:7.0.1'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife
//        classpath group: 'com.jakewharton', name: 'butterknife', version: '7.0.1'

    }
}
```

to gradle script.
After that，when i build project,got this error:

**Error:No route to host**

I use VPN and connect to google.com fine.

How can i fix this problem

Answer (score -1):

You should delete the Google maven repo from your `app/gradle` and instead put it your project base gradle file :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
...
```